# How does this function give value 3 to mat[24][58] in c?

Tags: c, matrix, range

We had this problem on test in school and nobody explained why result is 3

```
#define x 60
#define y 30

int main() {

    int mat[x][y];
    register int* mat_pok;
    for (
        mat_pok = &mat[0][0];
        mat_pok <= &mat[x - 1][y - 1];
        ++mat_pok) {
        *mat_pok = 3;
    }

    mat[24][24] = 7;

    printf("%d", mat[24][58]);
}
```

I dont understand why is it 3 because range is [60] [30] and for loop is going from first to second last element in this matrix.

When I paste this code in vs it does show 3 but also an error (reading invalid data from 'mat[24]';readable size is '120' bytes but '240' may be read).

Comment: You get the error message because `mat[24][58]` is technically out of bounds, the last element of the array being `mat[59][29]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are observing the affect of undefined behavior per 6.5.6 (standard):

> If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

or spelled more clearly in J.2 (informative):

> — An array subscript is out of range, even if an object is apparently accessible with the given subscript (as in the lvalue expression a[1][7] given the declaration int a[4][5]) (6.5.6).

Why does it give the value 3 anyways?  You fill the array with 3.  The expression `mat[24][58]` means the same as `*(*(mat + 24) + 58)`.  It just so happens that my compiler (and probably yours too) translate that `*(int *) mat + 24 * 60 + 58` which is equivalent to `mat[25][24]`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define x 60
#define y 30

int main() {
    int mat[x][y];
    int *mat_pok;
    for (mat_pok = &mat[0][0]; mat_pok <= &mat[x - 1][y - 1]; ++mat_pok) {
        *mat_pok = 3;
    }
    mat[24][24] = 7;
    printf(
        "&mat[24][58]: %p\n"
        "&mat[25][28]: %p\n",
        &mat[24][58],
        &mat[25][28]
    );

    printf("%d", mat[24][58]);
}
```

which returns:

```
&mat[24][58]: 0x7fff7623f718
&mat[25][28]: 0x7fff7623f718
3
```

You to respect array bounds, obviously, as the compiler can help you catch logic errors.

Comment: *so you access the array within bounds.*  I'm not entirely sure that's strictly conforming.  `mat[24]` is an array of 30 elements, and 58 is well beyond the confines of that particular element.

Comment: This isn't correct because the compiler isn't obliged to generate deterministic code for the `mat[24][58]` access.

Comment: Your array `mat` is a a chunk memory that starts at the address `&mat[0][0]` and is `sizeof(int) * 60 * 30` long.  When I refer to *within bounds*, I specifically refer to that chunk.  The notation, `mat[24][58]` is short hand for `*(*(mat + 24) + 58)` which is the same as `*((int *) mat + 24 * 60 + 58)`

Comment: @Lundin you are probably right.  Do you have a reference that tells us that it's undefined behavior?  I do think it's the correct answer to Op asking for an explanation of the behavior even if we just happen to be lucky.  The pointer addresses proves that point.

Comment: Similar question here: [Is it undefined behaviour to just make a pointer point outside boundaries of an array without dereferencing it?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277215). The source is the same, C17 6.5.2.1 regarding additive operators. Summarized as: "If both the pointer
operand and the result point to elements of the same array object ... otherwise, the behavior is undefined." And as demonstrated in that answer, you _can_ provoke the compiler to produce bananas code if you go out of bounds, so this isn't just pedantic language-lawyering.

Comment: @Lundin I don't think it's the same, actually, as their example points outside the the array.  I was just looking at 6.5.2.1 and I actually think because of the equivalence rule to pointers it's ok.  Another argument, perhaps, is that `a[17]` is the same as `17[a]`  Clearly a is out of range for the address 17 in the way you (and I for that matter) think about it.

Comment: @AllanWind That question was merely about pointing out of bounds. This code here is accessing out of bounds, so it's worse. You are allowed to point _one item beyond the end of the array_ as a special rule (but you can't de-reference there). But you aren't allowed to point or access 58-30 =28 items beyond the end of the array.

Comment: @Lundin I still haven't found anything to support your assertion.  Particular that the bounds check applies to each dimension in a multi-dimensional array.  We are in agreement about the single dimension case.

Comment: There is formally no such thing as multi-dimensional arrays. There are just arrays of arrays.

Comment: @Lundin 6.5.6 (8) has discussion you referred to ". If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined."  6.5.2.1 defines "Successive subscript operators designate an element of a multidimensional array object." so I think it's pretty clear you are wrong on that one :-)  "array of array" (and plural) are only mention once in example comment.  Anyways, I don't want to waste your time, I was curious about specification answer.

Comment: @Lundin got it... "An array subscript is out of range, even if an object is apparently accessible with the given subscript (as in the lvalue expression a[1][7] given the declaration int a[4][5]) (6.5.6)." J.2.

Comment: @AllanWind 6.5.2.1 just says that if you declare an array `int E[i][j][k];` then `E[x]` gives you a pointer to an `int [j][k]` array - that is an `int(*)[j][k]` pointer. None of that allows out-of-bounds access.

Comment: @AllanWind I see why I might have confused you, I said C17 6.5.2.1 in my first comment but that's just about subscription. But I said "regarding additive operators" and actually meant 6.5.6. Anyway the link I gave to Codidact has the correct chapter numbers and citations. The problem is just that it isn't obvious why the additive operators have anything to do with arrays, why you need to start reading 6.5.2.1 first...

Comment: @Lundin followed references to array from the index.  Updated answer based on what I learned.  Is the answer agreeable now?

Comment: Yeah that's fine but you shouldn't quote Annex J since it's just an informative summary. 6.5.8/8 is the normative text. And yeah it's quite an evil paragraph to read - only this part is relevant: "If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last
element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: I updated it with the relevant text from 6.5.6 as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

`&mat[0][0]` is the memory address of the first element of the array.

`&mat[x - 1][y - 1]` is the memory address of the last element of the element of the array.

So this loop fills the whole array with the value 3:

```
 for (mat_pok = &mat[0][0]; mat_pok <= &mat[x - 1][y - 1]; ++mat_pok)
 {
   *mat_pok = 3;
 }
```

For the rest see Allan Wind's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define x 60
#define y 30

int main() {

    int mat[x][y];
```

here you declare a matrix `mat` of `60` by `30` elements, all contiguous in memory.

```
    register int* mat_pok;
```

Here, you declare a pointer to `int` to initialize all the matrix elements.

```
    for (
        mat_pok = &mat[0][0];
```

you assign the pointer the address of the first element of `mat`.  This could be abreviated as: `mat_pok = mat;`, or better `mat_pok = mat[0];`

```
        mat_pok <= &mat[x - 1][y - 1];
```

Here you test the pointer to be less than or equal to the address of the last element in the array.  This statement could be abbreviated as `mat_pok < &mat[x][0];`, as `&mat[x][0]`  would be the address of the first next element to the last element of the matrix.  While some people has answered to this question talking about undefined behaviour (here?), there's no undefined behaviour as you are allowed to point a pointer to one array cell further than the last cell of the array, for comparing purposes.  In your case you point to the address of the last array element.  A bidimensional array has `x * y` consecutive cells.

```
        ++mat_pok) {
```

you increment the pointer to point to the next element.  The pointer will wrap, first cell by cell, then row by row, until the whole array is covered.

```
        *mat_pok = 3;
    }
```

here you initialize each array element to `3` by making the pointed cell equal to 3.

```
    mat[24][24] = 7;
```

here you assign the value `7` to the cell in row 25, col 25.  So you have all the array elements initialized to 3, except the one at cell `[24][24]` which is `7`.

```
    printf("%d", mat[24][58]);
}
```

here you print the cell located in `[24][58]`, row 25 (`<= 60`) and col 59 (`>= 30`) so, indeed, you are accessing the cell positioned at row 26 and col 59 - 30 == 29, which is indeed the position used by `mat[25][28]`, so you'll get a `3` as output, as this should be the value stored in there.  There's no undefined behaviour here.  C doesn't check array bounds, so you'll be accessing the cell that is 58 cells apart from `mat[24][0]`, but that cell is not in row 24, but in row 25.  You have not gone outside of the array, so no undefined behaviour (but a bit arbitrary) is happening here.  It is not illegal.  Indeed, the whole array was initialized under the assumption that all the elements where consecutive, one after the other.